# Moving UP and DOWN on 360° video with a SAMSUNG FLIP 4 touchscreen

Tags: aframe, touchscreen

Good morning,
I used A-FRAME to play a 360° video on a LOCAL web page (using WAMP) on a SAMSUNG FLIP 4 TV connected to a computer. When using a mouse on this video, there are no issues when I hold the left click and move it up and down or left and right. However, when I disconnect the mouse to use a stylus (or my fingers), I can move from left to right, but nothing happens when I try to move up and down. Do you know why and how to fix this issue? For reference, here is the piece of code I used.

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 col-md-8">
                <div id="fullscreenContainer">
                    <div class="video-container">
                        <a-scene id="myScene">
                            <a-sky src="#video" rotation="0 -130 0"></a-sky>
                        </a-scene>
                    </div>
                    
                    <video class="mx-auto" id="video" crossorigin="anonymous" playsinline webkit-playsinline loop muted>
                        <source src="<?php echo $video; ?>" type="video/mp4">
                        Votre navigateur ne supporte pas la lecture de la vidéo.
                    </video>
```

Kind regards

Geoffrey